# What is the citation-system for the Linear B tablets?

Tags: mycenae

I continued my research about Mycenea and I´m reading Chadwicks "The Myceneaen World", which is based a lot on the Linear B tablets. When citing them, it looks like this:

> We also found tablets in Thebes about sacrifices **(Of 26)** ...

Others would be (Fr 1231) or (Xd 97). 
How do I find the related tablets and their translation? Are there publications that simply list all tablets that are found plus a translation?

Answer (score 4):

Linear B is in a curious condition - its corpus was in a terrible disarray because of their discoverer, [Sir Arthur Evans](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/2009/aug/13/knossos-fakes-facts-and-mystery/?pagination=false), a passionate but undisciplined archaeologist who did as much harm as good to the body of knowledge surrounding the ancient world. It took a long time for scholars to piece together a complete catalog of Linear B and its translations, mostly because they needed to recover them from the obscure and uncataloged collections that Evans deposited them in, especially the pieces that didn't conform to his odd notions.

After a considerable amount of effort, modern experts in the field came together to create a book that collects, catalogs and translates everything recovered so far: [Corpus of Mycenaean Inscriptions from Knossos](http://books.google.com/books/about/Corpus_of_Mycenaean_Inscriptions_from_Kn.html?id=KO6T82zI8noC) (Only Volume IV is on Google Books - it's an expensive set of books, so hit up your local lending library.) This is the work modern scholars refer to - I'm not certain if it contains a cross-reference to the old reference system.

The controversy continues, however, with the discovery of the [Thebes Tablets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thebes_tablets) and a few scholars going rogue - so it may be a few more decades before the complete corpus and its translation is available.